# Grokking Why Factorials are in the Denominator of Taylor Polynomial Terms

Tags: taylor-expansion

**Context:** I intuitively understand why the first two terms of a Taylor polynomial can approximate the value of a function $f(x)$ where $x$ is sufficiently near $a$ and information about $f$ on $a$ is already known:

$$
f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a) (x - a)
$$

This makes sense since, if we let $\Delta a = (x - a)$ and $\Delta f(a)$ = $f(x) - f(a)$, then

$$
f'(a) \approx \frac{\Delta f(a)}{\Delta a} = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{(x-a)} \implies f(x) - f(a) \approx f'(a) (x - a)
$$

Moreover, it makes sense why the third term in the Taylor polynomial is multiplied by $(x - a)^2$:

$$
f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a) (x - a) + \frac{f''(a) (x - a)^2}{2!}
$$

since

$$
f''(a) \approx \frac{\Delta \left( \frac{\Delta f(a)}{\Delta a} \right)}{\Delta a} = \frac{\Delta(\Delta f(a))}{(\Delta a)^2} = \frac{\Delta (\Delta f(a))}{ (x - a)^2} \\ \implies \Delta ( \Delta f(a)) \approx f''(a) (x - a)^2
$$

**Question:** But where does the division by $2!$ show up (and more generally division by $n!$ for each $n$th term)? What motivates it *from the point of view of using Taylor series to approximate a function near a point*?

---

**EDIT:** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) provides the formula for second-order "forward" difference as follows.

$$
f''(x) \approx \frac{\Delta_h^2[f](x)}{h^2} = \frac{ \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x+h)}{h} - \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} }{h} =  \frac{f(x+2h) - 2 f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^{2}}
$$

Using the notation from above, here $h$ takes the role of $(x - a)$.  Since $h^2$ is in the denominator of this result, it makes sense why we'd have to multiply by $(x - a)^2$ to cancel it out.  But it remains totally unclear why divided by $2!$ helps us approximate $f$!

Comment: Note that the derivative of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is $\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$

Comment: Do we have something like $\Delta ( \Delta f(a) )) / 2! \approx \Delta f(a)$?  If so, then I would understand what is going on I think?

Answer (score 2):

The $n!$ is the $n$th derivative of $x^n$ at the point $x=0$.

Couple that with the fact that a polynomial is its own Taylor polynomial.

Comment: Is there any connection between this and my approximate expansion of $f''(a)$?  Or more specifically, can the approximate expansion of $f''(a)$ in my post be modified to include $2!$ somewhere?

Comment: I don't think your approximation for $f"(a)$ makes sense.  Try writing it out with actual differences between values at $a$ and $x$ rather than manipulating the $\Delta$.

Comment: I added a more explicit formula for the second order forward difference (an approximation of $f''(x)$ using concrete values).  It still remains unclear to me why $2!$ belongs in the denominator of the Taylor term, from this point of view.

Comment: I also found Wikipedia's list of [Higher-order difference quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient#Higher-order_difference_quotients) which explicitly uses $\Delta$'s, and don't see any motivation there for putting $2!$ and $3!$ in the denominator of the 2nd and 3rd Taylor terms, respectively.  Trying to understand Taylor polynomials from the point of view of difference quotients looks like it might be a dead end.